# Programmatically set rangeSelector in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I've defined several buttons for the range selector (1d, 7d, 1m, 3m, 1y).

And they work as expected.

But I want to change the zoom level programmatically because depending on which item I select, the zoom level should have a different default.  I don't see anything in the docs that do this.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by saying "zoom level"? In Highstock the extremes after the zoom operation are generally the same as the selected area.

Comment: @KamilKulig I mean the zoom range selector buttons.  Want to be able to trigger them through code.

Answer (score 1):

You can call range selector button's click event programmatically like this:

`chart.rangeSelector.buttons[X].element.onclick();`

where:

- `chart` is the variable that refers to the chart object
- `X` is the index of the range selector button

Comment: Is that an onclick event or does that actually trigger the button?

Comment: It triggers the function that launches as a callback on button's click event.